# Integrating square

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have following equation given.

$$\int_{} \frac{(vdv)^2}{A^2+\sqrt{3}}$$
$$=\frac{v^3}{3 \sqrt{3} A^2}$$

In the first equation I have $(vdv)^2$. There's square on $dv$ also. So, is my integration correct? I found [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693076/simplifying-square-of-integral-in-general) similar to this. In that question most of people used multi-variable calculus. So, Does it mean this question doesn't make any sense?

---

I found a website which is called [Calculus Calculator](https://www.mathway.com/Calculus). I had tried simple equation with that website. I found following result.

[image]

Question :

$$\int (xdx)^2$$

Answer :
$$\frac{1}{5}d^2x^5+C$$

---

I got [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125536/integrating-square/4125637#4125637) but, I would request to explain it

Comment: What does $(dv)^2$ mean on a single integral?

Comment: Here is a video about [$$\int\sqrt{\mathrm dx}$$](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dXKORECURQI)

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Actually, I don't know.

Comment: The given epression is meaningless.  It should be $$\int\frac{v^2\,dv}{A^2\sqrt{3}}$$ in order to get the answer $$\frac{v^3}{3\sqrt{3}A^2}$$

Comment: @TymaGaidash Isn't there difference between $$\int \sqrt{dx}$$ and $$\int (dx)^2$$

Comment: @GEdgar That is given..

Comment: @Istiak  Hello! The point of the video was to illustrate the differential raised to a power is integrable, but is not integrated like a regular $I=\int f(x) \mathrm dx$. It looks like you are mistaking $I^2\ne \int f^2(x) \mathrm (dx)^2$ for all f. This is not the case. Using multivariable calculus means two integrals and the notation of $(dx)^2 $ as the differential is not used. What are you integrating with respect to and is your $(dv)^2$ a differential or a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried the problem in [this site](https://www.mathway.com/Calculus). I got following result.

$$\frac{d^2(A^2-\sqrt{3})v^5}{5(A^4-3)}+C$$